# Null pointer exception for a multithreaded java code

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I am having a problem with a Java code that is using SimJava simulation library. The library basically helps with creating independent entities that can run as a java thread. The problem I am having is that I have a code segment that is used as the body of each of the entities that are running as a thread. These entities/threads are sharing an event (that transfers a ConcurrentLinkedQueue) between these threads. I used the concurrentlinkedqueue as I had problems with LinkedList concurrency control.
The problem is that if I run the model for 100 repetitions or less, it works fine. If i go 100 or more i get a null pointer exception for the concurrent queue. Here is the code segment of the body that has the problem.

Null pointer exception happens at the line where I am trying to pull from queue even though the line before is checking if the queue is empty or null. The exception is thrown at the line 
"nextNode = dcPath.poll().intValue();”

For some reason the poll call is returning a null and the intValue() is being applied to a null object. My question is that how is this possible with the if statement before is already checking for the queue content? How can I control this race condition?

```
public void body() { 
  synchronized (this){
  ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> dcPath = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> ();    
  int nextNode;
  int distance = 0;
  while (Sim_system.running()) {
    Sim_event e = new Sim_event();
    sim_get_next(e);    // Get the next event
    dcPath = (ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>) e.get_data();
    if ((dcPath != null) && (!dcPath.isEmpty())){
      nextNode = dcPath.poll().intValue(); // THIS LINE IS THROWING NPE Exception
      if ((dcPath != null) && (!dcPath.isEmpty())){
        int outPort = findMatchingOutPort(dcPath.peek().intValue());
        if (outPort != -1){
          sim_schedule(out[outPort], 0.0, 0, dcPath); 
          distance = this.calculateSensorToSensorDistance (out[outPort].get_dest());
        }                 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: which line precisely is throwing the NPE? Please comment that line.

Comment: Since you are using the method intValue(), there is some kind of unboxing happening. What does the statement dcPath.poll() return? The return value might be null - which you are trying to unboxed to a primitive int

Comment: @Ashish: my thoughts exactly. He's chaining too much on one line and needs to check return values before trying to call methods on them. The question overall is a bit too cryptic.

Comment: @Ashish dcPath.poll() will return the head of the queue or a null if the queue is empty.

Comment: He's not checking for null before using it.Sheesh.

Comment: I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels
you need to check the return value of scPath.poll() for null before trying to convert it to a primitive int.

If you need further debugging - you will have to output on console to have a abetter idea why its returning null. Multithreading can be a headache!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels don't you think the check for `dcPath != null` and then `!dcPath.isEmpty()` would satisfy the contract for `dcPath.poll()` not being null, without a null check?

Comment: can you paste the implementation of dcPath.poll()

Comment: @Ashish do you mean the JavaDoc for [ConcurrentLinkedQueue#poll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#poll())?

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but it seems some of you are not even reading the content or not familiar enough with Java collection. Let me try to respond to the relevant comments:

Comment: The line that is causing the problem is: "nextNode = dcPath.poll().intValue();" and I have added a comment next to the line. As for the check for null, i think it is there and you can see it up there in the code sample. That is what is driving my question that I had posted. There is a race condition somewhere and the null check is not capturing the change to the concurrent queue dcPath. As for the question about dcPath.poll() implementation, this is a standard method in the ConcurrentLinkedQueue which can be found in Java documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem would be that when you retrieve the dc_path from e.get_data(), another thread is concurrently read/write into that queue. So you have your code with:

```
if ((dcPath != null) && (!dcPath.isEmpty()) {
```

Which, at the meantime, dcPath is not empty. But when executing the next line, another thread pop up the remaining element and make the queue empty, and that's why you get the `dcPath.poll()` a null value.

To prevent this, you need to synchronize your dcPath reference instead of `this`. Like following:

```
if (dcPath != null) {
    synchronized (dcPath) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

And also, in any other thread which involve in read/write with the object, you need also sync it to make sure behave as you expected.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the change you suggested did help, but did not resolve the problem completely. It basically extended the ability of the model to run for about 200 iterations, but if I try to go beyond that, it throws the same exception for the same line.

Comment: Sorry I miss the "dcPath.isEmpty()". The reason still be that if you want to read/write the dcPath queue, you must determine if it is empty inside a block of synchronize. like `synchronize(dcPath); if (dcPath != null && !dcPath.isEmpty()) { //do something}`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to resolve the issue, i wouldn't say this is the most efficient way (especially in terms of memory management) but it will do the job for my simulation model and the number of instances I need to run. 
I basically created a copy of the ConcurrentLinkedQueue dcPath object at each thread instance and moved and when the object. This eliminated the race condition when manipulating the object. I can now run more than a thousand iterations without any exceptions being thrown with extended threads that can exceed 500 instances.

```
if (e.get_data() != null){
       ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> dcPath = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>        
                                   ((ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>) e.get_data());
```